# Tornado url regex match: make the "\.html" optional

Tags: python, regex, tornado

What I wnat to do is merge two line to one.

```
handlers = [ 
    (r"/doc$", DocHandler),
    (r"/doc\.html$", DocHandler)
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `\.html` optional:

```
(r"/doc(?:\.html)?$", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.html` part as optional.

```
r"/doc(?:\.html)?$"
```